# Getting to variable by using an inteface

Tags: java, interface

I've got an object that is interface, let's call it **MyInterface** something.

**My interface is empty** and is being implemented by two classes.

First on has one variable int x, and the second one two: int x, int y.

Variables are private but they've got "get" methods and i know them.

> Is it possible to get to the variable of a class just by using "something"?

Comment: If you're using the interface then the design shouldn't *need* to know the specific implementation.  Your design is flawed.

Comment: I'm using java as in tag (should have mention it). The problem is that's not my design. All i can do is to write a class with a sigle method that get's this object "something". i Have to get to these variables but don't know how.

Comment: Please share some code to make the question less ambiguous.

Comment: You can add methods "getX()" and "getY()" to your interface, then implement them as needed in implementing classes

Comment: @evadin: If the interface should expose that value then add it to the interface.

Comment: You can cast your variable to its concrete class if you need to call a method not specified in the interface.

Comment: As i expected, seems like I have to contact with whoever wrote this interface, because most likely that's the issue. I just wasn't sure if i'm missing something. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (excluding reflection magic), unless you add a `getX()` method to `MyInterface`.  Then, it's easy and it has the nice side-benefit of being a correct design.

Comment: As @khelwood pointed out, you can cast the object to the implementing class, no reflection required.

Comment: True enough, if you know all possible implementing classes, you can use `if (a instanceof ClassA)...`.  It's still not good design, but it is a working answer to the question.  Why don't you post it?

Comment: I don't think I can give a good answer before OP clarifies the question (and adds some code). Agreed that the design sounds flawed.

Comment: Reflection magic is not that hard, but you get _zero_ help from the compiler.